# Using One Object in Multiple Classes

Tags: java, class, object

I'm trying to use a setter/getter class in multiple classes to modify a single variable. I understand that I have to use the same object in order for this to work, but I'm unsure on how to make a single object accessible to multiple classes.

```
public class accountbalance {
    private double balance;

    //getter
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    //Setter
    public void setBalance(double newBalance) {
        this.balance = newBalance;
    }

}
```

This is where I'm trying to use it first:

```
public class CreateAccount {

    String name;
    double social;
    int pin;

    public CreateAccount()
    {
        name = "null";
        social = 0;
        pin = 0;
    }

    public CreateAccount(String enteredName, double enteredSocial,int enteredPin, double value)
    {
        name = enteredName;
        social = enteredSocial;
        pin = enteredPin;
        double accountnum = 87495;

        accountbalance a1 = new accountbalance();
        a1.setBalance(value);

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(social);
        System.out.println("Your new PIN is " + pin);
        System.out.println("Your new account balance is " + (a1.getBalance()));

    }
}
```

And then I'm trying to use it again here:

```
public class deposit {

    double enteredAmt;
    double amt;

    public void deposit() {
        System.out.println("Enter an amount to desposit: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        enteredAmt = in.nextDouble();

        accountbalance ab1 = new accountbalance();

        System.out.println("current balence: " + ab1.getBalance());

        amt = ab1.getBalance() + enteredAmt;
        ab1.setBalance(amt);
        System.out.println("Your new balance is " + (ab1.getBalance()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using SharedPreferences? Look it up. I think it's what you need.

Comment: If you have time, could you please explain your use case just a bit more.  There are a ton of different ways to answer your question, but knowing what you're actually trying to do could help limit the amount of typing.

Comment: It's a practice assignment. The createaccount() class creates an "account" with an initial value. The deposit() class adds a value to the balance. When the deposit class is run, it resets the balance back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is use the [Command Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

If you changed your classes to look more like this, things might work a tad bit better.

```
public class Account {

    // Please do not use SS for an identifier.
    private String identifier;

    private String name;

    // Money needs to be stored in it's lowest common denominator.
    // Which in the united states, is pennies.
    private long balance;

    public Account(String identifier, String name) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = 0L;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return this.identifier;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public long getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void credit(long amount) {

        balance =+ amount;
    }

    public void debit(long amount) {
        balance =- amount;
    }
}
```

Then here would be your CreateAccountCommand.  It is a bit anemic, but that is ok.

```
public class CreateAccountCommand {

    private String identifier;
    private String name;

    public CreateAccount(String identifier, String name) {

        // Identifier sould actually be generated by something else.
        this.identifier = identifier;
        name = name;
    }

    public Account execute() {

        return new Account(identifier, name);
    }
}
```

Here is your DepositCommand:

```
public class DepositCommand {

    private Account account;
    private long amount;

    public DepositCommand(Account account, long amount) {
        this.account = account;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void execute() {

        this.account.credit(amount);
    }
}
```

WithdrawCommand:

```
public class WithdrawCommand {

    private Account account;
    private long amount;

    public DepositCommand(Account account, long amount) {
        this.account = account;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void execute() {

        this.account.debit(amount);
    }
}
```

Then run everything:

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String... args) {

        CreateAccountCommand createAccountCommand = new CreateAccountCommand("12345678", "First_Name Last_Name");

        Account account = createAccountCommand.execute();

        System.out.println(account.getIdentifier());
        System.out.println(account.getName());
        System.out.println("Your new account balance in pennies: " + account.getBalance());

        // Deposit $100.00
        DepositCommand depositCommand = new DepositCommand(account, 10000);

        depositCommand.execute();

        System.out.println(account.getIdentifier());
        System.out.println(account.getName());
        System.out.println("Your new account balance in pennies: " + account.getBalance());

        // Withdraw $75.00
        WithdrawCommand withdrawCommand = new WithdrawCommand(account, 7500);
        withdrawCommand.execute();

        System.out.println(account.getIdentifier());
        System.out.println(account.getName());
        System.out.println("Your new account balance in pennies: " + account.getBalance());
    }
}
```